# What is a sub-base?

Tags: meaning

I found the term *sub-base* [in *To Have And Have Not*](http://archive.org/stream/ToHaveAndHaveNot/TXT/00000098.txt) by Ernest Hemingway (1937):

> "We'll have to steal the boat. You know they ain't got her fixed so I can't start her."
>    "How you going to get her out of the **sub-base**?"
>    "I'll get her out."

I can't find this word in any dictionaries, either online or offline. I guess this is a kind of basin for boats or yachts. Is it a building for holding boats?

Comment: _Sub-base_ is short for _submarine-base,_ just like _sub_ is short for _submarine._

Comment: I've edited your question to include a link to the original. Please make it a habit to provide full context, always.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer CAN be found on multiple different websites ranging from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_base) to [The Free Dictionary Site.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/submarine+base)

According to *Wikipedia*:

> A submarine base is a military base that shelters submarines and their personnel.

According to *The Free Dictionary,*

> A base providing logistic support for submarines.

So, your definition is partially correct, but instead of boats and yachts, subbases hold submarines.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others have said...

As a submariner myself, and still living 15 miles away from the Groton, CT Sub Base (we don't hyphenate it, for some reason), I can tell you that if subs were in context, then everyone else is correct.

I'm no grammar authority-I just rode them for 6 years! :)

pat
:)

P.S. There might well also be a term out there for a sub- (as in sub-division) base of any kind. That is, a base of operations that has nothing to do with subs (submarines). I'm no Hemingway expert, so I don't want to rule that possibility out in my answer.. :)